# Creating a resizable sidebar in Qt4

Tags: c++, qt4, sidebar

I want to create a sidebar in `QMainWindow` that is resizable any idea how can I do it ? thanks :)

PS : Here is an example from `Qt Assistant`
[image]

Comment: Well, easiest would be to use the QSplitter and make the layouts within the splitted area listen to the resize ( should be doable in QT Designer pretty much ) - to be found in  contents/qt designer manual/qt designer's widget editing mode

Answer (score 0):

well, you might wanna download Visual Studio Professional and make it "dialog based" while you set up the project. and open the file filename.rc to edit the dialog. There are lots of controls that I've haevn't used yet. To get to the controls menu, go to toolbars on the side of the IDE, and you should see something with the word controls in it.

Comment: What is this text?